# Have been use without time

Tags: tense

‘I have been in worse problems’ is this statement gramitically and syntactically correct?
I have tried searching in Google and also on quora
But I got both positive and negative answers

Comment: As I told you on ELU, you should say  "I have had worse problems" or "I have been in worse situations". The present situation is bad, but not as bad as some you have experienced before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What strikes me as wrong (or at least not natural) in this sentence is "in problems". One has problems, but isn't usually in them.

> I have been in worse situations.

and

> I have encountered worse problems.

are better.

(This does not address your direct question - whether the sentence you wrote is grammatically or syntactically correct.)